# Get previous element with one in between

Tags: jquery, events, event-handling, jquery-events

I am programming something that has two buttons with the same functionality.

Rather than putting all the information from the first button into the second one, I added an even handler to the second to trigger a click on the first so the same code will be run.

I'm using the jQuery framework so if possible could I get suggestions in jQuery format.

This is the code I was using for the event handler:

```
$(document).on('click', '.enlargeComments', function(){
    
    $(this).prev('.commentsLink').trigger('click');
    
});
```

The button with all the functionality is created by a PHP class, so getting the information to place it onto the second will not work, also giving it an identifying class would also mean making additional changes to the class which isn't ideal to be honest.

However now I have another button which comes in between these two and my event handler no longer works... I need a solution to get my original one workings so no suggestions to change the way it's currently working please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.prevUntil(sel).prev()` to do this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.enlargeComments', function(){

    $(this).prevUntil('.commentsLink').prev().trigger('click');

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Why would you do that?

Just attach the same handler to both elements since they will be doing the same thing anyway:

```
$(document).on('click', '.commentsLink, .enlargeComments', function(){

    //click stuff

});
```

Comment: Hi the additional button does not appear everywhere, so It's better to have a separate event handler for the sections it does appear.

Comment: @AndréFigueira that is **not** true at all. You are just delegating the event to wherever it does occur.

Comment: As I explained in the description, the first button, the comments one contains attributes which affect the content being loaded, this button is generated from a class, the other not, to get the event handler to work in the way suggested would mean copying the data to the other button also, which as I mentioned isn't what we want happening